# Object with starts_on and ends_on best query suggestion

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, date-range

I need to select from a table that has a `starts_on` field and an `ends_on` field.
I need to pass start date and end date for filtering and retrieving those objects.

At the moment it's working and I use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM ***
WHERE ((starts_on >= START_DATE AND starts_on <= END_DATE) OR
       (ends_on >= START_DATE AND ends_on <= END_DATE) OR
       (starts_on <= END_DATE AND ends_on >= END_DATE))
ORDER BY starts_on, id
```

It looks a bit messy, but can't see an easy way to simplify it. Any idea?
I'm using postgres 9.1 as dbms.

Edit:

```
 starts_on   | timestamp without time zone | 
 ends_on     | timestamp without time zone |
```

Ex: if one entry has starts_on = '2012/02/02' and ends_on '2012/02/05' I want the following behavior:

- if I filter by start date 2012/01/01 and end date 2012/03/01 I want the item to be returned
- if I filter by start date 2012/02/04 and end date 2012/03/01 I want the item to be returned
- if I filter by start date 2012/02/05 and end date 2012/03/01 I want the item to be returned
- if I filter by start date 2012/02/04 and end date 2012/02/04 I want the item to be returned
- if I filter by start date 2012/02/06 and end date 2012/03/01 I want the item to NOT be returned
- if I filter by start date 2012/01/01 and end date 2012/02/01 I want the item to NOT be returned

Comment: Please provide the exact table definition (with relevant columns), which is essential for the question. Also explain how you want to filter exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Query

If you want all rows where the time period between `starts_on` and `ends_on` overlaps with the passed time period of `START_DATE` and `END_DATE`, and "end" is always later than "start", and all involved columns are of type `timestamp` (as opposed to `time` or `date`), this simpler query does the job:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  starts_on <= END_DATE
AND    ends_on   >= START_DATE
ORDER  BY starts_on, id;
```

Fits the question as later clarified.

#### Index

The best index for this query would be a [multi-column index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) like:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_range_idx ON tbl (starts_on, ends_on DESC)
```

Would work with `DESC / ASC` almost as well, because an index can be searched in both directions almost equally well.

How do I figure?

The index is searched on the first condition `starts_on <= END_DATE`, qualifying rows are at the beginning.
From there, Postgres can take all rows that end late enough according to `ends_on >= START_DATE`. Qualifying rows come first. Optimal index.

But don't just take my word - test performance with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html). Run a couple of times to exclude caching effects.

There is also the [`OVERLAPS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html) operator for the same purpose. Simplifies the logic, but isn't superior otherwise.

And there are the new [`range` types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rangetypes.html) in PostgreSQL 9.2, with their own operators. Not for 9.1 though.

Comment: I added more explanation above in my question

Comment: @CLod: In short: you want all rows where the time range *overlaps* with the filter in any way. Coincidentally, my answer already covers that.

Comment: thanks! another kind of related question: I currently have index on starts_on and another one on ends_on. Is it better if I have an index on both fields if I always use both of them for filtering?

Comment: @CLod: I added a bit on indexing. Note my edits - previous version was sub-optimal.

Comment: yes added indexes at the end, noticed that it reduced query cost. thx heaps